# Windowing in kafka streams not respecting given window size

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I want to buffer events for 60 seconds, aggregate them and process the batches, but it seems that the window size is always a couple of seconds, no matter what I define as a window.

I use spring kafka streams, and this is how the consumer looks like

```
            Materialized<String, List<String>, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized;
            materialized = Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ListSerde(ArrayList.class, Serdes.String()));
            materialized.withLoggingDisabled();
            materialized.withCachingEnabled(); //cache needs to be enabled, otherwise windowing will not work
            materialized.withRetention(Duration.ofSeconds(65));

            return kstream -> kstream
                    .peek((k, v) -> LOG.info("incoming event: {}", v))
                    .groupByKey()
                    .windowedBy(TimeWindows
                            .ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                            .advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(60)))
                    .aggregate(ArrayList::new, (key, b, c) -> {
                        c.add(b);
                        return c;
                    }, materialized)
                    .toStream()
                    //.foreach((k,v) -> processor.process(v));
                    .foreach((k, v) -> LOG.info("processing {}, {}", k, v));
```

The log message is printed 15 seconds after the incoming events arrive.
Any ideas? Do I have so somehow alter the commit interval?